# Volley sends two requests

Tags: android, android-volley, android-networking, android-debug

I really have a big problem, i want to register some user, and service sometimes (1 in 20) will return username not unique error.

So while debugging  with the database developers they are telling me that there are 2 requests sent for < 100ms

So i got only the second response that the username is not unique. (So the user is successfully created and i am showing the error " Username not unique " )

Please tell me how can i solve this, i tried to set returnPolicy...

```
            setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            30000,
            0,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

but no luck..

Comment: Send a UUID along with the request and have the service return "successful" if a second request with the same UUID comes through within a specified time period. When you're working with mobile data, missed ACKs are always possible, and you need to design your services around that.

Comment: @323go , i want to send only ONE request, i have no idea why Volly is sending double request but i want to prevent that.